# Is it possible to compare two variables inside an array with for-each loop?

Tags: c++, foreach

Is there any way to compare two elements in an array with a for each loop in cpp?

```cpp
int [] s {1,2,3,3,3,4,5};
int size = 7;
for(int i = 0 ; i< size;i++){
if(s[i] == s[i+1]){
//instructions 
}
}
```

Is it possible to do the same by

```
for(int x : s){
//required part to be answered
}
```

Is it possible to do this type of comparison with foreach loop ?

Comment: The first code has multiple errors. Arrays don't have a `.size()` member (they don't have *any* members) and if you replace it with an array-like container that has `.size()` like `std::vector` you will eventually compare with `s[s.size()]` which is always undefined behavior.

Comment: There are different tools offered by the language you should each use for the right use cases, and if you do so, use them correctly.

Comment: going to edit it thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it possible to do this type of comparison with foreach loop ?

**Short answer:** No.

**Long answer:**

The closest you can get to is:

```
for(int& x : s){
   int* p1 = &x;
   int* p2 = p1 + 1;
   if ( *p1 == *p2 ) { ... }
}
```

Howeve, when `x` corresponds to the last element of the array, `p2` points to an element beyond the last element if the array. Dereferencing `p2` at that point is cause for undefined behavior.

It will be better to stick to the first method, after you've fixed the compiler errors and the logic errors.

```
int s[] = {1,2,3,3,3,4,5};
int size = sizeof(s)/sizeof(s[0]);

for(int i = 0 ; i < size - 1; i++){
   if(s[i] == s[i+1]){
      //instructions 
   }
}
```

Comment: There is also [`std::adjacent_find`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/adjacent_find) possibility.

Comment: Thank you very much going to select this answer!

Answer (score 0):

No, You can't do this type of comparison in case of for each loop.

Answer (score 0):

If the compiler supports C++ 17 then you can use the range-based for loop for example the following way

```
int a[] = { 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5 };

for ( int prev = 0; const auto &current : a )
{
    if ( prev == current ) std::cout << "Adjacent elements equal to " << prev << '\n';

    prev = current;
}
```

I suppose that the first element of the array is not equal to 0.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use directly for-range for that.

Standard provides [std::adjacent_find](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/adjacent_find) which can help:

```
int s[] = {1,2,3,3,3,4,5};

for (auto it = std::adjacent_find(std::begin(s), std::end(s));
     it != std::end(s);
     it = std::adjacent_find(std::next(it), std::end(s)))
{
    // instructions
}
```